# Why does converting the_geom into lat/long gives me more than 1 coordinate?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgadmin-3

I'm converting my `the_geom` into lat/long coordinates but I only want a single coordinate since I'm gonna use the coordinates to draw a polyline in google maps.
Attached is the picture of the result of my query.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your result is the line strings needed to draw the actual route. This is probably what you want, but if needed you could break them down in to individual points by hand.

Comment: thanks for the answer, that cleared things up. but is there a way to convert them into a point(lat,long) rather than in a linestring? I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Please read the manual page about https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DumpPoints.html.